# brain.js correct training of the neuralNetwork

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, neural-network, brain.js

I must clearly have misunderstood something in the [brain.js instructions on training](https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com#training)

I played around with this [repl.it code](https://repl.it/@Norfeldt/BrainJS-Playground)

```
const brain = require('brain.js');

const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

network.train([
    { input: { doseA: 0 }, output: { indicatorA: 0 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.1 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.02 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.2 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.04 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.3 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.06 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.4 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.08 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.5 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.10 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.6 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.12 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.7 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.14 } },
]);

const result = network.run({ doseA: 0.35 });

console.log(result);

>> { indicatorA: 0.12165333330631256 }
    => undefined
```

was expecting the results to be `{ indicatorA: 0.07 }`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increasing the number of iterations and decreasing the error threshold worked for me:

```
const brain = require('brain.js');

const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

network.train([
    { input: { doseA: 0 }, output: { indicatorA: 0 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.1 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.02 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.2 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.04 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.3 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.06 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.4 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.08 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.5 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.10 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.6 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.12 } },
    { input: { doseA: 0.7 }, output: { indicatorA: 0.14 } },
], {
  log: true,
  iterations: 1e6,
  errorThresh: 0.00001
});

const result = network.run({ doseA: 0.35 });

console.log(result);
//
```

Result : `{ indicatorA: 0.0693388432264328 }`

Comment: Is there a good rule of thumb on how to determine if more training is needed or adjustment to `iterations` or `errorTresh`?

Comment: More data can help @Norfeldt.

Comment: More data is always better @robertplummer ;-) but is it better to provide more of the same data (so fx two dose 0.5) or new data (dose 0.8)?

Comment: I am not sure how the error threshold is computed in brain.js. It is not well documented and I don't feel like reading through the documentation, but really even 100 iterations should produce a better result than what brain.js initially produces.